# How to Make Certain Phrases Appear on One Line Regardless of Screen Size

Tags: html, css, text

I have the following heading

`<h2>John Smith Fine Art</h2>`

How can I style this such that the phrase Fine Art is always on one line without having to change the font-size based on screen size? For example, as the window is made smaller (such as on an I-Phone), the heading may appear as

```
John Smith Fine
Art
```

I am OK with having

```
John Smith Fine Art
```

or

```
John Smith
Fine Art
```

but not when there is a line break between "Fine" and "Art" as with the first example. How can I achieve this? If "Fine Art" was all one word, that would achieve my goal so theoretically I could perhaps add a _ between "Fine Art" and style it with CSS so that it was invisible to give the effect of having a space, but that would affect my SEO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an `&nbsp;` (non-breaking space) character in between the words to indicate that lines should not break there.

Example: `<h2>John Smith Fine&nbsp;Art</h2>`

Comment: I was hoping for an easy fix like this